# How to multiply arrays of different shapes?

Tags: arrays, numpy

I have a problem with multiplying arrays with different shapes.

```
[1,2,3,0,0] and [4,3,2,0]
```

I have converted them into arrays and now I want to multiply them together.
this is my code so far

```
a= np.array(p_list) 
b= np.array(q_list)
c= a*b
```

Comment: What do you expect the result to be?

Comment: @matt actually 16 but this is just part of a task, after multiplying the arrays we have to add the elements together and the answer should be 16 so I think I'm expecting [4 6 6 0 0] from the multiplication

Comment: So what is the rule of your "multiplication"? Do you just keep the length of the shorter array?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you just want to truncate elements off the larger array, and you are only using 1D arrays

```
a = np.array([1, 2, 3, 0, 0])
b = np.array([4, 3, 2, 0])

min_length = min(a.size, b.size)
c = np.multiply(a[:min_length], b[:min_length])
```

result: c = [4 6 6 0]